# JS alert not happening before php header/location change

Tags: php, redirect, alert

This is an interesting one...
I am trying to test for something, then show an `alert` then once the OK is clicked relocate the page to somewhere else, using `header` 
However if I have the code below it just goes straight to the URL.
If I comment out the `header` then the `alert` works....

```
elseif ($user['archived']=="1"){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Sorry you are no longer an owner');</script>";
    sleep(10);
    header('location: https://some URL'); 
}
```

Comment: You are doing a header redirect on the server so that will occur even before the html / javascript makes it to the browser. If you need to execute javascript first, you would need to wait and redirect in javascript as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Completely get the Server Side, Client Side thing, but dont see how its a duplicate of the article..  Its a question on how to fix it.  The article explains the difference.  I couldnt figure out why even with the 'sleep' it was still not 'doing' the alert, before it got to the header command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a meta redirect instead. I'm not sure if this is good or bad practice but it will do the trick for you.

```
if (...) {
    // ...
} elseif ($user['archived']=="1") {
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; URL=someurl">';'
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Sorry you are no longer an owner');</script>";
    exit;
}
```